# Duplicated workflow with correlation

Tags: workflow-foundation-4

I have workflow with correlation. When I call twice some method with the same parameters i have the following error:

*The execution of an InstancePersistenceCommand was interrupted by a key collision. The instance key with value 'bcd874f3-1d47-d9f0-de51-4487d1e4e12e' could not be associated to the instance because it is already associated to a different instance.*

Is there any way to delete previous workflow and start new?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a [WorkflowControlEndpoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee358723.aspx) to the WorkflowServiceHost and use the [WorkflowControlClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.activities.workflowcontrolclient.aspx) to terminate the existing workflow before starting a new one with the same correlation key.

Comment: Thanks, but to terminate workflow I need its InstanceId. I don't known it. Especialy I doesn't know if workflow exists.

Comment: You know there is a workflow with the same correlation id. So you can either add a service operation to return the instance id from the existing workflow. An alternative is to use property promotion to make the value used for correlation query-able in the instance store and get the instance id that way.